# Google Chrome rendering its own styles

Tags: css, google-chrome

I'm changing over a site from HTML to Wordpress (for the first time, so be gentle!) and I ran into an issue with Google Chrome applying styles that I've never knew existed! In this case I'm referencing the style that positions the bg.gif image background.  In both IE9 and Firefox the background elements seem to work just fine, but in Google Chrome I'm having the issue.

If you go to this site: http://www.richmindonline.com/doggy2/ then right-click the upper right corner of the page in Google Chrome, then click "Inspect Element", you will notice styles that are being applied that have nothing to do with my stylesheets.

Could someone provide some guidance as to how to fix this. I've already tried adding my own styles to trump the Chrome styles, but it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which styles are you trying to override? What you're seeing are browser defaults - all browsers have them whether they show you or not.

What I'm seeing in the inspector is Chrome identifying the text direction and locale. Are you using a CSS reset?

http://www.cssreset.com/

Should go a long way in starting all browsers at the same default.

Comment: I'm just trying to make the background image get inline with the primary background color.  Is it messing up on your page when viewed in Chrome? I now have CSS reset added for HTML5 but it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: I think it looks right on my end unless I'm not looking at the right thing: http://awesomescreenshot.com/0d54y0n07

Comment: OK.....I just change like 30 seconds ago, so it may have been fixed temporarily when you viewed it. Can you try once more and let me know as of now? Sorry for the bother.

Comment: No worries. Still looks good on a clear cache: http://awesomescreenshot.com/01d4y0z99

Comment: Chords - it was uTorrent tool bar - I noticed the adjustment in a special script after clicking in the "Resources" area, then I could see the adjustment was the exact height of my uTorrent toolbar. It also said in the script something about a toolbar adjustment, so I took a shot and it worked